# Почему массив не видит число?

Tags: c++

Вся проблема в том, что в терминале выводит огромные числа - 633345927 HP, -32757 HP
которых не должно быть

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>


class Soldier
{
public:
    int healthPoints, attack;

    void getValues(int number)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        healthPoints = rand() % 5 + 1;
        attack = rand() % 5 + 1;
        std::cout << number << ". " << "HP: " << healthPoints << ";";
        std::cout << " ATK: " << attack << "     ";
    }
};

int main()
{   
    const int SIZE = 4;
    int firstArmy[SIZE];
    int secondArmy[SIZE];

    std::cout << "FIRST ARMY           ";
    std::cout << "SECOND ARMY" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Soldier firstArmy[i];
        firstArmy[i].getValues(i);
        Sleep(1000);

        Soldier secondArmy[i];
        secondArmy[i].getValues(i);
        Sleep(1000);

        std::cout << "" << std::endl;
    }
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        Soldier firstArmy[i];
        Soldier secondArmy[i];
        secondArmy[i].healthPoints -= firstArmy[i].attack;
        firstArmy[i].healthPoints -= secondArmy[i].attack;
        // std::cout << i <<". " << firstArmy[i].healthPoints << "-" << secondArmy[i].attack << " = ";
        std::cout << secondArmy[i].healthPoints << " HP" << std::endl;
        std::cout << firstArmy[i].healthPoints << " HP" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: встречные вопросы: 
1) почему ```firstArmy```  объявлена как массив ```int```? 
2) что по вашему мнению делает строка ```Soldier firstArmy[i];```?

Comment: у вас массивы `firstArmy` и `secondArmy` объявлены дважды и отличаются друг от друга типами элементов. массивы внутри цикла имеют очень короткое время существования (постоянно создаются  при каждом цикле массива). Внутри цикла внутренние массивы объявлять **не** надо.

Comment: 1) Удалите объявления массивов внутри циклов. Они _скрывают_ внешние объявления в начале функции `main`. 2) Замените типы массивов в начале `main` с `int` на `Soldier`. 3) Массивы индексируются с нуля: `for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)`. 4) `srand(time(NULL));` — эту штуку вынести в начало `main`, т.к. её _многократные_ вызовы существенно _ухудшают_ качество генерируемых псевдослучайных величин.

Comment: @wololo, ухушают? Вы мастер осторожного слова. Они превращают генератор в тыкву (форма которой меняется раз в секунду). По вызовам `Sleep(1000)` видно что автор о чём-то таком догадывается. :)